# ffmpeg command with chained filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg and to this forum and I'm in need of creating some complex (at least for me) animations. Please excuse my bad english or explanations.

I'm using ffmpeg version 4.4

**Input(s):**

- img1.jpeg (will loop 14s)
- img2.jpeg (will loop 14s)
- first video (created for 14s from img1.jpeg) will start with a `fade in` filter from frame 0 to 25
- a `xfade` filter applied between looped img1 and looped img2
- `smartblur` starts at second 4 and stays on until second 20
- a white transparent `drawbox` (opacity 0.3) shows from second 5 to second 20
- audio.mp3 is added on background with the -shortest flag at the end
- frame rate is forced to 25 on the final video with `-r 25`

**Output:**

- final video with filters and audio on background

**My command:**

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 14 -i img1.jpeg -loop 1 -t 14 -i img2.jpeg -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=13[video];[video]fade=in:0:25[video];[video]smartblur=5:1:0:enable='between(t,4,20)'[video];[video]drawbox=x=0:y=20:w=iw:h=ih-40:color=0xFFFFFF@0.3:t='fill':enable='between(t,5,20)'" -i audio.mp3 -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -s 848x480 video.mp4 -y`

**Complete ffmpeg command log:**

```
time ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 14 -i 57ac8b5655e926a994d57857f92dcffa.jpeg -loop 1 -t 14 -i b53dc57419455354319c1cfb1b047924.jpeg -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=13[video];[video]fade=in:0:25[video];[video]smartblur=5:1:0:enable='between(t,4,20)'[video];[video]drawbox=x=0:y=20:w=iw:h=ih-40:color=0xFFFFFF@0.3:t='fill':enable='between(t,5,20)'" -i a950b90762b39d6dae38c9d06f8cf1d3.mp3 -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -s 848x480 video.mp4 -y
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, image2, from '57ac8b5655e926a994d57857f92dcffa.jpeg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 31104 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, image2, from 'b53dc57419455354319c1cfb1b047924.jpeg':
Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 34629 kb/s
Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, mp3, from 'a950b90762b39d6dae38c9d06f8cf1d3.mp3':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Duration: 00:00:27.59, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 64 kb/s
Stream #2:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.35
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> xfade:main (graph 0)
Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> xfade:xfade (graph 0)
drawbox (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Stream #2:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7f8600008000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x7f8600018000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] using SAR=40/53
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] 264 - core 161 r3049 55d517b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'video.mp4':
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 848x480 [SAR 40:53 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 libx264
    Side data:
    cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 aac
frame=  675 fps=112 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1120kB time=00:00:26.98 bitrate= 340.1kbits/s speed=4.48x    
video:668kB audio:429kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.141831%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] frame I:6     Avg QP:14.68  size: 50615
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] frame P:172   Avg QP:18.93  size:  2109
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] frame B:497   Avg QP:28.86  size:    34
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] consecutive B-frames:  1.6%  0.3%  0.9% 97.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] mb I  I16..4: 18.3% 63.3% 18.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  1.3%  0.1%  P16..4:  6.1%  1.4%  1.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:89.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.2%  L0:24.9% L1:73.9% BI: 1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] 8x8 transform intra:69.9% inter:62.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 76.1% 81.2% 66.6% inter: 1.3% 2.0% 0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 73%  8%  4% 15%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 22% 13%  6%  7%  6% 10%  7% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 18%  8%  6% 10%  8% 13%  7% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 21% 15% 13%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:7.0% UV:6.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] ref P L0: 81.4%  6.9% 11.4%  0.3%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] ref B L0: 92.6%  7.1%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] ref B L1: 95.2%  4.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7f862c029e00] kb/s:202.41
[aac @ 0x7f862c02ce00] Qavg: 188.226

real    0m6.225s
user    0m10.558s
sys 0m0.399s
```

**Question:** *Being new to this amazing tool, how can I improve the command above to generate the exact same output as it does now? I'm sure it's not optimal and there is a lot to improve. Processing speed being very important.*

Thank you for any help/idea!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt direction @llogan! I've read the tour and I've updated the question.

Comment: Show the complete log from your ffmpeg command.

Comment: @llogan Log added. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command looks good and you're not using an old ffmpeg with a bad configuration. Some minor suggestions:

#### libx264

You are encoding with libx264 so you can add the `-preset` and `-crf` options to control speed and quality as described in [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

#### VideoToolbox & AudioToolbox

Because you are using iOS/macOS you can try VideoToolbox and AudioToolbox.

Add `-c:v h264_videotoolbox -c:a aac_at`.

It may be faster. I've never tried these encoders because I don't have the required hardware. libx264 provides a higher quality than h264_videotoolbox per bitrate. aac_at may be better than the built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder.

More info: `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_videotoolbox` & `ffmpeg -h encoder=aac_at`.

#### Everything in `-filter_complex`

The legacy `-pix_fmt` and `-s` options are aliases for the format and scale filters. Use the filters instead so you can have more control when they are applied within `-filter_complex`. Because you are upscaling the scale filter should be last for faster processing (may be insignificant in this case but this is a general recommendation).

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -t 14 -i img1.jpeg -loop 1 -t 14 -i img2.jpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=13[video];[video]fade=in:0:25[video];[video]smartblur=5:1:0:enable='between(t,4,20)'[video];[video]drawbox=x=0:y=20:w=iw:h=ih-40:color=0xFFFFFF@0.3:t='fill':enable='between(t,5,20)',format=yuv420p,scale=-2:480" -shortest video.mp4
```

I omitted `-r 25` because the default frame rate for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) is 25.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer! The tests are done locally on my machine but when in production, we're going to use EC2 Ubuntu instances and I guess `h264_videotoolbox` and `aac_at` aren't going to be needed, isn't it?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Correct.